# Tabs in custom implementation of grocery crud

Tags: php, grocery-crud

I am using grocery crud (GC) with a custom php code (not for CI). I want data in tabs in edit page. I have found this "[GC CRUD Tabs](https://github.com/blakdronzer/POWER-GCrud)" extension for CI but I don't know how to have (integrate) that functionality for custom php implementations.

i tried

```
$crud->fields(['tabs','dbname','dbpass','dbserver']);
$tabs = array ( 
array('Test Tab','dbname','dbpass')
,array('Test tab2','dbserver')  
); 
$crud->callbackEditField('tabs', function ($tabs, $primaryKeyValue)
{
print_r($tabs);
});
```

But it failed with error "cannot read property 'isReadOnly' of undefined" as "tabs" is a fake field.(to be changed to original tabs on callback).

Comment: Any code to share on what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have updated the question.